After using union join, I can't sculpt
Screenshot for clarity:

I used union join to smoothen the way the different parts were joined (neck to head, head to muzzle, etc. etc.) and these squares appeared. I was following a YT tutorial and it had those too so I ignored it. Now I came to sculpt the mouth, however no matter what I do I cannot sculpt anything in the head; not the muzzle, not the horn, nothing. The only thing I am able to sculpt is the torso (I joined the wings to the torso using Ctrl+J) and I sculpted the wings and it worked so I dont' know.
The issue could be something other than union join, who knows. I have shade smooth turned on. How can I sculpt? Is there a way to fix this?
Thank you!

Hello could you please share your object or at least a part of it?

@moonboots yea sure, how can i do that? would you like my .blender file?

use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or another platform like workupload

@moonboots https://workupload.com/file/cuBRrJjuEYU here u go!

I can sculpt your objects but first thing apply the scale in Object mode (Ctrl A) and also recalculate the normals in Edit mode (Shift N)

@moonboots that worked, thanks! wish i could mark it as answer

Apply the scale in Object mode (CtrlA) and also recalculate the normals in Edit mode (ShiftN)
